# Setting LayoutParams with few Lines of Code

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there an easy and simple way to set LayoutParams ? Or to be exactly, the MarginLayoutParams? I want to set the MarginRight to a few dp, unfortunately im not able to set these in the LayoutFile cause the Target is a ListFragment and in Code-Behind looks it very ugly.
The reason i do this not in the Layout of the items is so the code is optimized and perfomant.

To sum up: Is there any very simple and clean way to set Params ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
  MyImageView i2 = new MyImageView(context);

  LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(300, 300);
  lp.LeftMargin = 100;
  lp.TopMargin = 100;
  lp.Gravity = 0;

  this.AddView(i2, lp);
```

Comment: thats the way i do it right now, but its so much overhead. Setting the context, building an extra object for Layoutparams, then setting the values and last giving the view the margins. So is there no other way to just set the margins ?

Comment: Not that I know of. That's the way I found I could do it. I don't need to set the context as this comes from the constructor of the custom FrameLayout in which I'm using this LayoutParams instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
lp.setMargins( left, top, right, bottom );
```

You might need to write it as LinearLayout.LayoutParams, depending on what type of layout is the container.

And then you call the method `setLayoutParams( lp );` on the given view/layout/widget.